# Confused about numpy's returned eigenvectors

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I've been playing around with numpy's linalg module and wanted to get the eigenvectors for the following matrix:

```
import numpy as np
matrix = np.array([[4,0,-1],[0,3,0],[1,0,2]])
w,v = np.linalg.eig(matrix)
print(v)
array([[0.70710678, 0.70710678, 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 1.        ],
       [0.70710678, 0.70710678, 0.        ]])
```

Calculating the eigenvectors by hand gives me only two vectors which are [1,0,1] and [0,1,0]. I know that numpy normalizes the vectors which is fine but the problem is when I try to check if the first and second columns are equal:

```
v[:,0] == v[:,1]
array([False,  True, False])
```

This gives me the impression that these are two different vectors (so I now have a total of 3 eigenvectors) when I already know I'll only get two.

Can someone please explain what's going on here.

Comment: I don't think this is an issue with the eigenvectors, it looks like floating point number comparison.

Comment: check `print(v[:,0] - v[:,1])` to confirm that, it is probably `[0.13e-15, 0.0, 0.21e-15]`